# Missing Angle Bracket Key when using G613

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, bluetooth

I'm using the Logitech G613 Bluetooth Keyboard with my 2019 MacBook Pro.

When I try to use the <kbd><</kbd> key on the Bluetooth Keyboard it prints "^" while the key left to the <kbd>1</kbd> key prints "<".
In the "Input Sources" setting I can see a keyboard layout with the <kbd><</kbd> key (next to left shift key) missing:

[image: Keyboard layout missing the "<" key]

After using the built-in keyboard the displayed layout switches to the correct layout with the angle bracket key. The key works fine on the built-in keyboard. After using the bluetooth keyboard the layout switches back to the previous one.

[image: Correct Keyboard layout displayed when using built in keyboard]

Does anyone now how to tell macOS that this key exists on the G613?

Comment: Hi martin, did you find a solution ? I have the same problem.

Comment: Same basic question here:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/304819/british-mac-keyboard-and-key-the-wrong-way-around?rq=1

Comment: @iizno Have you tried either of the two answers here?

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to set a device-spesific key change using [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/). If you can't easily set that, you can make a (custom) rule by finding a custom rule on karabiner's website, and then modifying it.

Comment: This worked, i needed this configuration : https://imgur.com/dTNU5Qo

Answer (score 0):

The machine seems to think your external keyboard has the wrong "type", namely ANSI instead of ISO.  [This page](https://m10lmac.blogspot.com/2009/12/fixing-keyboard-type-problems.html) provides some possible fixes.